# Starting Mongod with both --auth and --bind_ip local host, my_IP_address, couldn't retrieve the memory of local host

Tags: mongodb, authentication, networking, server, ip

I am able to successfully run the mongod with `--auth`. I am also able to run mongod with `--bind_ip 127.0.0.1, my_IP_address`. But when I combine and run `mongod --auth --bind_ip 127.0.0.1, my_IP_address`, the bind_ip is not considering the local data saved earlier with just "mongod".

Please help me out in starting the mongod server with both auth and bind_ip.

Comment: If you really have a space after the comma, `my_IP_address` becomes a separate command-line argument which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: @D.SM, I am able to run mongod --bind_ip successfully, but I would need --bind_ip and --auth while starting mongod server. With authentication in robo 3T is connecting perfectly for local host, but authentication failed when I tried connecting with my_IP_address